# Eeeek! My robot is addicted to SO!

Tags: discussion, users, robots

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/306656/user306656) looks *a little* suspicious. Just 1 rep, no questions, no answers, and a fanatic badge. Pretty sure it won't pass the "I'm a human" test.

**Yet another edit** : I don't know whether it's a bot or a real user. It looked strange to me and thus I pointed it out. **I don't know enough about website security to even try to figure out what a user bot could do**. As Grace commented, *even if it were a bot*, it's not a real concern. Also, as Nick showed me, it's most probably a real user. Case closed.

Comment: The description of the badge says "Visited the site each day for 100 consecutive days." This user has been a member for over a year, and visited the site for 110 consecutive days.

Comment: I know the rule, I just wanted to point out the user so you can take a look at it.

Comment: Doesn't matter, it passed the rules. Besides, anyone who's so desperate as to program a bot to earn a small little gold circle on a website *is* a fanatic.

Comment: Bots like badges, too. Give google a badge or two and you might see page rankings increase.

Comment: @waiwai I could not care less about the badge that "user" earned let him have it! I just don't understand why somebody would make such bot, and raised the concern, that's it.

Comment: I'm now wondering here, how did you even find that username if there are zero answers and questions posted with it?

Comment: @mario I was curious and looked who had the badge here: http://stackoverflow.com/badges/83/fanatic . You can see one user with rep 1, so I clicked to see the profile.

Comment: But if you're not concerned about a bot, then what's the problem here?

Comment: [That's not the only one](http://stackoverflow.com/users/157084/guid). But I don't really think it's a problem or anything to be concerned about, myself.

Comment: @Grace good to know.

Comment: Is the `Eeeek!` necessary? Overusing it Weeeaken it.

Comment: @meta.DavRob60 it was not my first title. I used it to clarify that this was not another "what's a fanatic badge" queeeestion.

Comment: related: http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/1800/toddler-is-afraid-of-robots

Comment: He replied to Robert Harvey's probe question.  I'm satisfied that he's just a lurker and not a bot.

Comment: I cannot stop thinking of this:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B1BdQcJ2ZYY

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that there are some bad assumptions here, quiet users != bots.  Both [the user in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/users/306656/user306656) and [in Grace's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157084/guid) are legitimate (if quiet) *human* users.

Their browsing/hit patterns and usage show this, for example [the user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/306656/user306656) in the question [likes to browse around favorite quite a bit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/306656/user306656?tab=favorites).

Comment: Eeek! My robot is addicted to SO and now _shows preferences_! The robot revolution can't be far away now.

Answer (score 7):

Nice try, human.

Answer (score 4):

What makes you so sure [that user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/306656/user306656) is a bot? Just because they didn't ask or answer questions doesn't mean they aren't *reading* or *learning from* questions and answers. Maybe they just like to observe. Notice that they have in fact [marked a number of favorites](https://stackoverflow.com/users/306656/user306656?tab=favorites).